# Some data series extend beyond axis limits in bokeh graph

Tags: python, bokeh

The figure below shows a portion of a plot created with the Bokeh plotting library (version 0.12.13 running under Python 3.6.4), using the `bokeh.plotting` interface.

[image: time series plot]

The graph was created by adding various time series glyphs to a figure, as in the following pseudo-code:

```
p1 = Figure(...) # create the axes and so on
p1.segment(...) # add the red line segments
p1.line(...) # the dark blue line
p1.quad(...) # the green rectangles
p1.quad(...) # the light purple rectangles
```

The dark blue time series line is correctly clipped to the limits of the axis frame. But the other glyphs extend beyond the horizontal axis limits (e.g. in the plot above, the red, green and purple segments and quads drawn in the axis label area).

The horizontal axis is set to show only a portion of the data (10 s of 120 s worth of data). On figure creation, the axes run from t = 0: 10 s, and the out of bounds glyphs occur only on the right (there is no data for t < 0), but following scrolling, glyphs appear out of bounds to the left as well, presumably because data now exists that is below the minimum axis value.

Is this a bug in the latest bokeh release, or is there some parameter to explicitly control whether data series extend beyond the axis limits?

Comment: Are you using `output_backend="svg"` or `"webgl"` ? There are known issues with those in some situations. Use the standard default output backend, which looks like it should be perfectly fine for this plot.

Comment: @bigreddot You're right, the issue is resolved by using the `'canvas'` backend. But the much greater scrolling performance when plotting half a million points means I'll tolerate this visual glitch and keep using `'webgl'` (`'svg'` choked on it completely). Thanks for identifying the source of the bug though. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: For 500k points you can also look at [Datashader](http://datashader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which integrates well with Bokeh.